# Styling Dropdown: Get and sum height of sibling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have this dynamic markup, in which the number of list elements is defined by my DB, so I can never know neither use static id's or classes to recognize each one:

```
<ul>
  <li>element1</li>
  <li>element2</li>
  <li>element3</li>
  <li>element4</li>
  <li>element5</li>
  <li>element6</li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to edit each list's css in order to position it using "top:XXpx", just like [this plugin does](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/index.html) but without prototype, and without all the functions that create the markup, because I already have the markup

thankyou!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do try first and ask to community. Share your trial code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select you li's with `'ul li'` in jquery and then give it any css you want

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/pm3dm02p/)**

```
var top = 0;
var zIndex = $('ul li').length;
var width = 300;
var left = 0;
$('ul li').each(function(){
    top = top + 5;
    zIndex = zIndex - 1;
    width = width - 4;
    left =  left + 2;
    $(this).css('top', top+'px');
    $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    $(this).css('width', width+'px');
    $(this).css('left', left+'px');
 });
```

here i just add some global variables with some intinal values and in the loop for each `li` i used these variable to set css properties for each li depending on its order.

So as example: each one will have top which increase 3 from the last one (except z-index as i want the last one has the less value so i started with the biggest number(based on li elements number to be dynamic) then decrease it in each element).

edit: giving elements  `position:absolute;` in css is important to make it look like the example you want.

Comment: @user3799253 check this i hope it helps.